# i want Latest Product of Home Page also show on Product Detail page

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Can you please guide me, how can i show Latest products of Home Page on Product Page detail. What steps we need to do this? Recently i have copy code from new.phtml and past into view.phtml. But nothing showing on Product Page. I think i'm missing something.. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mawais24,

follow below steps to put new products any where.

1. Go to static block.
2. There is a option for insert widget in block content field editor. [image]
3. Select "Catalog New product list" from dropdown. [image]
4. Then Insert widget.
5. After that put below code in product->view.phtml
   [image]

Comment: Thank you so much it's working :-) i set design of latest products my own which is already showing on home page, i put same code into new_list.phtml but same design not showing on product detail page. Please compare bellow link, 
See home page Latest product Slider:
http://t1.mygarden.pk/
See Product Detail page Latest product Slider:
http://t1.mygarden.pk/bulb-flowers.html

Comment: Welcome...:) I think div tags were not closed. I would suggest to check the code properly.

Answer (score 1):

mawais24,You  have call `new.phtml code at view.phtml` but it did not work because of

`new.phtml`  block class is `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New` and view.phtml file render class is `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`.

As you was pasted all code of new.phtml at view.phtml so those pasted  code  rendered class code is taken to   `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`  from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New`

it is Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View class function `is not content the all code of Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New`

So.create an `layout xml` and using this call `new.phtml  as view.phtml's` file  as child block

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_new" name="new_products_details" template="your new.phtml location" />
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

then add below code

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('new_products_details') ?> in your view.phtml
```

**Alter solution:**
Put this code at view.phtml

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_new')->setTemplate('catalog/product/new.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: Dear Amir thank you for Reply. I have created new xml file with name of layout.xml then past your code in this file, then call by using this 
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('new_products_details') ?>
in view.phtml. But latest product not showing on details page. What i missed again?

Comment: create local.xml not layout.xml

Comment: Dear Amit i change layout.xml to local.xml but still not working :-(

Comment: <block type="catalog/product_new" name="new_products_details" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" />

is that right or not?